# Makefile on Win 64

Tags: makefile, windows64

I am working on Windows 64 and we need a makefile  for our project. We have an existing makefile foe Win 32 and  don’t know how to set the 64 bit environment from make file.
If  anyone did it or have any sample makefile of Win 64 then please share with me.
We are getting the following error

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(17) : error C2371: 'size_t' : redefinition; d
ifferent basic types
        predefined C++ types (compiler internal)(19) : see declaration of 'size_t'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winnt.h(81) : fatal error C1189: #error :  "No Target Architecture"
make[3]: *** [shared/anonObject.o] Error 2
```

which is mainly came when in VS  x64 bit configuration is not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the 64 bit environment on command prompt then ran the makefile with /MACHINE:X64 option.

Comment: Command was “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC>vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64”

Answer (score 2):

That error (*No Target Architecture*) is thrown by the preprocessor if neither `_AMD64_` nor `_IA64_` are defined, which, I believe, either hints you set the target architecture incorrectly (should be done passing `/MACHINE:X64` to `cl`), or you are working with a really exotic one...

I don't know about any other specialties concerning 64-bit compliation, except, of course, you need to run the 64-bit version of `cl` (the one in `VC\bin\amd64`).

For that matter, also remember to link using the 64-bit libs instead of the 32-bit ones.
They can be found in their respective `lib\x64` (Windows SDK) and `lib\amd64` (Visual Studio) folders.

---

The fact that `size_t` is already defined can probably be fixed using

```
#define _SIZE_T_DEFINED
```

before including `sourceannotations.h`. Are you defining `size_t` by yourself? It's done in `windows.h`, which should define the above automatically.

Comment: /MACHINE:X64 is still not working and this need at linking time. I don't know how to set Win 64 configuration( x64 configuration in sln file) in the make file.